# why labels location are changed after running

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem when I position my labels in visual studio.net then when I run the application the labels location are changed.

As it shown on the image bellow:

1 shows in the designing mode before running.
2 shows when I run the app.

I am using these lines of code to prevent any changed of the form size by the user:

```
    Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
    Me.MaximizeBox = False
    Me.MinimizeBox = False
    Me.CenterToScreen()
```

The completed code:

```
Public Class game2
    Private Sub game2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        LblPoint.Text = GlobalVariables.points
        Me.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.MinimizeBox = False
        Me.CenterToScreen()

        lchair.Parent = Background
        lclock.Parent = Background
        lclothe1.Parent = Background
        lclothe3.Parent = Background
        lcloth2.Parent = Background
        ldrower.Parent = Background
        llamp.Parent = Background


        ' Start the timer.
        lblTimeLeft.Text = (GlobalVariables.m & ":" & GlobalVariables.s)
        game.Timer1.Start()
    End Sub
end class
```

[image: 1. in the designing mode. 2. in the running mode.]

[image]

Comment: It is impossible to answer this question given the small amount of code you provided.

Comment: If you comment out those lines of code, do the labels stay where you put them?

Comment: No even if I comment them

Comment: Sorry I just add the complete code

Comment: I just comment the lines of parent property and the labels stays where they are. but how can I make the label transparent without those lines?

Comment: Background is a  pictureBox

Comment: I will use panel instead of pictureBox. Thanks all.

Comment: I would prefer to use pictureBox because when change the picture, it will be changed smoothly. however the panel background flashes at every change. So any suggested solution ?

Comment: If you set `Me.Label1.Parent = Me.PictureBox1`, the Label location will be relative to the new parent container (the PictureBox). Reposition it accordingly.

Comment: even if I add me nothing changed. I just figure out that the label go down because the background is not cover the form instead I left a blank area above the background. when I make the pictureBox cover all the form the labels stays as they are :) The only  problem that I don't want the pictureBox to cover all the form  :(

Comment: The point is not the "Me" reference. When you set the your labels' parent, their **Location** will be relative to the **PictureBox**. Knowing this, you have to re-locate them, right after you have assigned their Parent, to the new relative position represented by the offset of the picturebox. Thus, their new Location will be `Labe1.Location= new Point(Label1.Location.X - PictureBox1.Left, Label1.Location.Y - PictureBox1.Top)`.

Comment: As a note: if you want to ping someone, you have to prefix their Nick with the @ symbol, otherwise nobody will be notified of your comments.

Comment: Thanks @Jimi for the solution and the explanation. your Answer is the best answer since it solved  the problem  :)

Comment: Good then. You could post a self-answer to the solution you coded.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is posted  by @Jimi in comments above.
I just create a function and call it whenever I add a label.

```
Private Sub setLabels(labelName As Label)
        labelName.Parent = Background
        labelName.Location = New Point(labelName.Location.X - Background.Left, labelName.Location.Y - Background.Top)

    End Sub
```